# Send POST request with meta data only using JSON API

Tags: angular, json-api, orocrm, orocommerce

I'm using JSON Api in my project and to implement it i used this library :
https://github.com/ghidoz/angular2-jsonapi.
So i'm trying to send a Post request with "meta" in body only and getting in response a meta.
Like sending this:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "email": "user@example.com",
    "password": "123"
  }
}
```

but i just dont know how to do it since all methods in this library take for argument JsonApiModel where there is always data in it, " meta " seems only optionnal and they dont talk about it or at least an exemple.

I also expect in return a meta like this

```
{   "meta": {     "apiKey": "e6d7535b5695a1b1d301b8ce52ed65131f8003a2"   } }
```

[Documentation of the API in Orocommerce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iP6I.png)

Comment: Would be great if you could elaborate a little bit on your use case. JSON:API documents with `meta` key only are not that common. I have never seen such as a request payload. Why is the server expected that `meta` information? What do you expect the server to return?

Comment: I also expect in return a meta like this  `{
  "meta": {
    "apiKey": "e6d7535b5695a1b1d301b8ce52ed65131f8003a2"
  }
}`  so i send a top-level meta object and get also a meta. We are using Orocommerce platform in back-end so i cant answer to why it should be like this. When i was looking in the documentations of JSON:API i found its possible to send meta object because its considered as a top-level member but i didnt find any exemple of implementation

Comment: Did you considered using native [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API instead of JSON:API client-side library?

Comment: I used  post method of HttpClient for the time being, it's working fine. But if i find a better solution i will probably change my code.

Comment: Neither your request nor the expected response are what I would consider as JSON:API. So I guess you would have an easier time if not trying to implement it with a JSON:API library.